# error Rebind result 'com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.animation.AnimatableDisplay' must be a class in mgwt 2.0 libary

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I build application in gwt.
I use gwt 2.5.1 sdk and mgwtphonegap 2.4 libary and mgwt 1.1.2 libary
and now I decided to upgrade the gwt sdk to 2.7 and mgwtphonegap to 3.5 and mgwt to 2.0
and now I get error when I During Compilation.
the row that cause the error.

`AnimatableDisplay display = GWT.create(AnimatableDisplay.class);`

the error:
Rebind result 'com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.animation.AnimatableDisplay' must be a class
how I can to resolve the problem
thank you everyone

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mgwt/mgwt2/mgwt/Cs2EHuvBD-g/gRW1gxXtTRAJ

Comment: https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/wiki/mgwt-2.0-Features

Answer (score 1):

From [mgwt group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mgwt/mgwt2/mgwt/Cs2EHuvBD-g/gRW1gxXtTRAJ)

```
Animations changed on create PhoneDisplay:

//AnimatableDisplay display = GWT.create(AnimatableDisplay.class); //mgwt 1.2.
AnimationWidget display = new AnimationWidget(); //mgwt 2.0
```

Comment: ok thank you for replay
this is help me but now I have another problem.
when I run on computer everything is ok but when i run on phone I get white screen and the gwt is not running I add this line `Window.alert("start");` in onModuleLoadand I saw the application not entering to onModuleLoad.
before the update all libraries
why the gwt not working
thank you